# Can't able to hide Share icon on the YouTube player using youtube_player_iframe in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

I am using youtube_player_iframe plugin in the Flutter application, I am able to hide all controls of YouTube but can't able to hide the share button from the player.

Here is my code:

```
 class VideoDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoDetail({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoDetail> createState() => _VideoDetailState();
}

class _VideoDetailState extends State<VideoDetail> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  RadioGroupController radioController = RadioGroupController();
  String lang = "English";
  String tempLang = "English";
  late int selectedIndex = 0;
  var links = <String>["Dx2HBxOXccs", "1AM5Fgb-qjA"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        showControls: false,
        mute: false,
        showFullscreenButton: false,
        loop: false,
        showVideoAnnotations: false,
        strictRelatedVideos: false,
        enableCaption: false,
      ),
    )
      ..onInit = () {
        _controller.loadVideoById(videoId: "Dx2HBxOXccs");
      }
      ..onFullscreenChange = (isFullScreen) {
        log('${isFullScreen ? 'Entered' : 'Exited'} Fullscreen.');
      };
  }

  void playVideo(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          YoutubePlayerScaffold(
            controller: _controller,
            builder: (context, player) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Column(
                  children: [
                    player,
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Screenshot of the page:

[image]

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround for this issue.

Information we want to hide is attached to container of the video, but not to video itself.

In my case I decided to set height of video-container a lit bigger and add two containers at the top and bottom of it with color of common background.
YouTube adjust video height and width according to width. Undesirable info exists under my two hiding containers.

Example:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 1100,
  width: 1600,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 1100,
          width: 1600,
          child: YoutubePlayer(
            controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
              videoId: videoId,
              params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
                showControls: false,
                showVideoAnnotations: false,
                enableCaption: false,
                pointerEvents: PointerEvents.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 1600,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 1000,
        left: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 1600,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```